How to destructure nested structs in polars (python api)?
I am unfortunately having to work with some nested data in a polars dataframe. (I know it is bad practice) Consider data:
data = {
    "positions": [
        {
            "company": {
                "companyName": "name1"
            },
        },
        {
            "company": {
                "companyName": "name2"
            },
        },
        {
            "company": {
                "companyName": "name3"
            },
        }
    ]
}

positions is a column in the dataframe. I have explored the polars python api docs but cannot figure out how to extract out just the companyName fields into a separate list column.
I want to achieve the same that this comprehension does:

names = (
    [
        p["company"]["companyName"]
        for p in data["positions"]
        if p.get("company") and p.get("company").get("companyName")
    ]
    if data.get("positions")
    else None
)

Note the null checks.
I get a sense that I have to use the pl.list.eval function along with pl.element but I am a bit foggy on the api.
Before:
shape: (3, 1)
┌─────────────┐
│ positions   │
│ ---         │
│ struct[1]   │
╞═════════════╡
│ {{"name1"}} │
│ {{"name2"}} │
│ {{"name3"}} │
└─────────────┘

After:
shape: (3, 1)
┌───────┐
│ names │
│ ---   │
│ str   │
╞═══════╡
│ name1 │
│ name2 │
│ name3 │
└───────┘


Are you saying you have df = pl.DataFrame([data])? Can you perhaps show before / after DataFrame examples?

Structs
You can use .struct.field() or .struct[] syntax to extract struct fields.

https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/expressions/structs/#extracting-individual-values-of-a-struct

df = pl.DataFrame(data)

df.with_columns(
    pl.col("positions").struct["company"].struct["companyName"]
)

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────────────┬─────────────┐
│ positions   ┆ companyName │
│ ---         ┆ ---         │
│ struct[1]   ┆ str         │
╞═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ {{"name1"}} ┆ name1       │
│ {{"name2"}} ┆ name2       │
│ {{"name3"}} ┆ name3       │
└─────────────┴─────────────┘

Alternatively, you can work at the frame-level and .unnest() the structs into columns.
df.unnest("positions").unnest("company")

shape: (3, 1)
┌─────────────┐
│ companyName │
│ ---         │
│ str         │
╞═════════════╡
│ name1       │
│ name2       │
│ name3       │
└─────────────┘

List of structs
If working with a list of structs you could use the .list.eval() API:
df = pl.DataFrame([data])

df.with_columns(
   pl.col("positions").list.eval(
      pl.element().struct["company"].struct["companyName"]
   )
)

shape: (1, 1)
┌─────────────────────────────┐
│ positions                   │
│ ---                         │
│ list[str]                   │
╞═════════════════════════════╡
│ ["name1", "name2", "name3"] │
└─────────────────────────────┘

Or at the frame-level using .explode() and .unnest()
df.explode("positions").unnest("positions").unnest("company")

shape: (3, 1)
┌─────────────┐
│ companyName │
│ ---         │
│ str         │
╞═════════════╡
│ name1       │
│ name2       │
│ name3       │
└─────────────┘


Okay, that seems simple enough. Could you please include the part about the null checks during this operation? Also would much appreciate some general outlines on such operations for cases where positions is of the type list[struct[1]]

@Arko You can use list.eval as you mentioned - but it depends on exactly what output you want. As for null checks - can you show a Polars example of how this would be needed exactly?

Columns in Polars have a single type/schema - and all values in the column must conform. So if you have structs they will all have the same keys - meaning null checks don't come in to play - as the keys must exist. Does that make sense?

Thanks for the clarification. I noticed in the second example the list.eval function takes care of the nulls as expected. So I am assuming that we do not need to explicitly handle nulls. As an example, let's say the positions of type list[struct[1]] was empty list for some rows in the df, or the struct field company was null or field companyName was null and to be handled as in the python comprehension snippet.

Yes, you would get an empty list or lists of null values in those cases.

Follow-up to the section about list of structs. I noticed in the example, that if the list positions is empty across all rows, then this fails with a StructFieldNotFound error for field company. Is there an idiomatic way to check for this?

How exactly are you creating the column? If there are no values that means no dtype can be inferred, so you may need to specify it. It sounds like you end up with list[null]? But that error sounds like it may be a "bug".

The column is being created from another column; from my actual code, it is something like
.with_columns(pl.col("payload").struct["data"].struct["positions"].alias("positions"))
It is correct that it infers the schema as list[null] in such a case.

Hm, ok. You coul try cast to get rid of the list[null] e.g. .cast(pl.List(pl.Struct({"company": pl.Struct({"companyName": pl.String})}))) but it may make sense to enforce the schema at an earlier step in "payload" to ensure list[null] isn't created in the first place.

Interestingly enough, in the current version of polars (1.11.0) the example with list.eval() doesn't work anymore.
It can be replaced with pl.Expr.explode()/pl.Expr.implode() workaround though:
df.with_columns(
    pl.col.positions
    .explode().struct["company"].struct["companyName"]
    .implode()
    # over is not needed in this example but
    # needed if there're multiple rows in the DataFrame
    #.over(pl.int_range(pl.len()))
)

shape: (1, 1)
┌─────────────────────────────┐
│ positions                   │
│ ---                         │
│ list[str]                   │
╞═════════════════════════════╡
│ ["name1", "name2", "name3"] │
└─────────────────────────────┘


1.11.0 broke certain queries for list.eval, it has been fixed. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/19345
